# DATABASE is corrupted --- cannot allocate space

Tags: ibm-domino

I had a archived copy of my email on the local system. Due to some problem my `C:` drive of the system got corrupted and i had already taken one copy of my archive folder.

After reinstalling the OS and Lotus Notes now i have kept the archive copy in the same folder `DATA\Archive\batabasename`. Now, when I try to access the archive it gives the message:

```
DATABASE is corrupted --- cannot allocate space
```

I tried to move the archived copy of the DB to server and applied following commands but non of them worked.

```
Load compact databasename -c
Load updall databasename -c
Fixup
```

I have Lotus version 7

Any idea ?

Comment: This is something you ought to take up with your IT department.

Comment: You have a corrupted file. There is missing and damaged data. If you have a backup copy, restore it. Otheriwse, you are almost certainly out of luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to repair this kind of file: 
- put it on a server (if it is not already)
- add the line SKIP_FIXUP=1 in the notes.ini of the server (this prevents the consistency check of the database)
- restart the server
- run the command "load compact databasename -M" (this error often occurs with an old ODS version database limited to 1 Gb and this command extend the db to 4 Gb) After that, you should open the database. May be this article will give you more information. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Database_Corruption_Troubleshooting_Guide

Comment: Thank you all for your advice! The issue has been resolved.